# HOG training and detection in Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having an issue with useful detection using Python, OpenCV 3.1 and HOG. While I have working code that executes without error, the trained HOG/SVM combination fails to detect on test images.

From OpenCV examples and other Stack Overflow discussions I've developed the following approach.

```
win_size = (64, 64)
block_size = (16, 16)
block_stride = (8, 8)
cell_size = (8, 8)
nbins = 9
deriv_aperture = 1
win_sigma = 4.
histogram_norm_type = 0
l2_hys_threshold = 2.0000000000000001e-01
gamma_correction = 0
nlevels = 64

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(win_size,
                        block_size,
                        block_stride,
                        cell_size,
                        nbins,
                        deriv_aperture,
                        win_sigma,
                        histogram_norm_type,
                        l2_hys_threshold,
                        gamma_correction,
                        nlevels)

window_stride = (8, 8)
padding = (8, 8)
locations = ((0, 0),)

histograms = []
# not showing the loop here but
# create histograms for 600 positive and 600 negative images
# all images are of size 64x64
histograms.append(np.transpose(hog.compute(roi, window_stride, padding, locations)))

training_data = np.concatenate(histograms)
classifications = np.array([1] * 600 + [0] * 600)

svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR)
svm.setC(0.01)
svm.setTermCriteria((cv2.TermCriteria_MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6))

svm.train(training_data, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, classifications)

# testing
test_img = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
svmvec = svm.getSupportVectors()[0]
rho = -svm.getDecisionFunction(0)[0]
svmvec = np.append(svmvec, rho)
hog.setSVMDetector(svmvec)
found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(test_img)
```

In every test, `found` is a single rectangle centered in the image and is not located where the positive is located in the test image.

I've tried many different combinations of parameters based on Stack Overflow answers and other OpenCV samples and discussions. None of them change the results.

Comment: Detailed and well organized explanation of the problem should be rewarded. May I ask the reason why you use only **svm.getSupportVectors()[0]**?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need all support vectors you have. So the problem is not your training code, it is your test.

```
svm.train(training_data, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, classifications)
```

You do your training with all data you have but when comes to testing, you only use a small part of your resulting classifier.

```
svmvec = svm.getSupportVectors()[0]
```

Change this line and you'll have one less problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why single rectangle is created at the center is because the detector classified almost all region as "human".
By default, detectMultiScale suppress the overlap of the rectangles. So you can only see the single rectangle at the center.
You can turn off this suppression with finalThreshold option of detectMultiScale.

```
hogParams = { 'finalThreshold': 0}
found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(test_img, **hogParams)
```

By default, this parameter is set to 2.
You can see almost all regions are filled by the rectangle color.

My answer to this "misclassification" is simple change of the order of the labels.

```
classifications = np.array([0] * 600 + [1] * 600)
```